# Add rule for maximum folder size limit for cloud storage in firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage

How can I add a rule to limit the maximum storage space size a user can consume? The current `request.resource.size` limits the size of a file a user can upload but not the folder/bucket size the user is uploading to. I wish to place a limit say 50 MB over all the content the user can upload.

Update:

To reframe the question, imagine the user has already uploaded 5 images of size 10MB each which makes it 50 MB altogether. Now I want to restrict the user from uploading any more files as the maximum bucket size (in my case: 50MB) is already reached. There could have been 2 files of 20 MB each and one of 10 MB, but the overall cap of 50 MB has to be respected. How do I add a rule for that?

Update 2:

Is it that in the current implementation, an authenticated user can keep on uploading an infinite amount of data say capped at 10 MB file size each at the expense of the user hosting the Firebase service (Assuming a pay as you go pricing model while hosting)?

Comment: Did you solve the problem? This question really deserves answer.

Comment: There is no direct way of limiting bucket size on firebase storage. Keep track of total folder size for a user in real time DB and put check on that before uploading/ update the value post successful upload. Alternatively, use cloud functions for the same. No one in google support to care for these things :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current design of Firebase does not allow creating rules to limit a bucket size.

A better implementation would be to track bucket size on your own server and also make all firebase uploads pass via your custom server. In essence, file gets uploaded to your server, passes bucket size check and then gets uploaded again to AWS S3 or Google Storage.

After this you can delete the upload from your server updating the metadata in your DB.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly do that on the client side by checking the file size.Check out this [File](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/File) api which has method size method.You can a check if the user has exceeded the file limit, then you can restrict him from uploading.

Comment: No, to reframe the question, imagine the user has already uploaded 5 images of size 10MB each which makes it 50 MB altogether. Now I want to restrict the user from uploading any more files as the maximum bucket size (in my case: 50MB) is already reached. There could have been 2 files of 20 MB each and one of 10 MB, but the overall cap of 50 MB has to be respected. How do I add a rule for that?

Comment: I don't think it is possible using rule.You have to manually keep track of user's usage or have a cloud function trigger which will update Db about the user's usage.All that is possible with rules are in this URL https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/security/storage/

Comment: And so without manually keeping track of this/ cloud function implementation, the user can just upload an infinite amount of data for free?

Comment: Yes because firebase cloud storage does not put size limit to the bucket